# Изменить ImageField() на TextField()

Tags: django

Как изменит тип поля FileField() на TextField() во время сохранение
например [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я изменит тип поля с js во время onChange в поле Категория
Фактическое поля модель fileField()

```
class Banner(models.Model):
banner_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
office = models.ForeignKey("Office", models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="офис")
category = models.ForeignKey("BannerCategory", models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="Категория")
banner_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Имя")
banner_resource = models.FileField(upload_to=rename("banner"), validators=[
    FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'mp4', 'MP4', 'webm'])],
                                   verbose_name="Баннер ресурс")
banner_status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Статус")

def clean(self):
    if self.category.category_module == "photo":
        if not str(self.banner_resource).split(".")[-1] in ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG']:
            raise ValidationError("Выберите только изображения")
    elif self.category.category_module == "video":
        if not str(self.banner_resource).split(".")[-1] in ['mp4', 'MP4']:
            raise ValidationError("Выберите только видео файл")


def __str__(self):
    if self.banner_name is None:
        return "-"
    return self.banner_name


class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'banner'
    verbose_name = 'Баннер'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Баннеры'
```

Comment: На самом деле не знаю, что нужно сделать. Но возможно это связано с методом save у модели, попробуйте поколдававать с ним, переопределить. Не уверен, что это сработает, но попытаться можно:)

Comment: Покажите ваши модели, пока нельзя дать конкретный ответ, чтобы это заработало

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете менять тип поля модели django в процессе работы. но вы можете создать второе поле, для текста, и показывать скрывать его через JS в админке